# Sync Web Apps Function Triggers - BadRequest (Azure)

Tags: azure-functions

I am working with Azure Function app with **`Java 17`** tech stack. I have three function triggers and one Azure function App. I have .yaml pipeline to deploy these functions, After successful deployment my functions are not updating in Azure Portal. When I checked the activity log I found two errors:

> Sync Web Apps Function Triggers - BadRequest

> No route registered for 'somepath/connectionstringvalidation/validate/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sync Web Apps Function Triggers - BadRequest

- This error could be due to the application setting `AzureWebJobsStorage` value set to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in `local.settings.json`.
- Update the value to the Azure Storage connection string or make sure the storage account is up to public.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your_storage_connection_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}
```

> No route registered for ‘somepath/connectionstringvalidation/validate/’

- This could be due to mismatch between the function runtime version and the Java version, check the function runtime settings and make sure the version is compatible with your Java version.

---

I have reproduced the same in my environment and could deploy the functions successfully.

Steps followed:

- Created a **Java Maven Azure function project** with **three Http Triggers** in IntelliJ and deployed to the **Consumption plan**-based function app with **Java 17** as runtime stack in Azure.

**Note:** I have used  ***Storage Connection string*** as value of application setting **`AzureWebJobsStorage`**

***Application settings of my Function App:***

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Function 1:**

[image]

**Function 2:**

[image]

**Function 3:**
[image]